# How can I use a Python Class attribute as a default value for a @Classmethod?

Tags: python, class-method, class-attributes

Take a look at the code below.

I want to use the value of `a` as the default value for argument `c` in the declaration of the classmethod `my_method()`.

How can I do it? The example below fails.

```
>>> class X:
...     a = 'hello'
...     def __init__(self, b):
...         self.b = b
...     @classmethod
...     def my_method(cls, c=X.a):
...         print 'cls.a = {}'.format(cls.a)
...         print 'c = {}'.format(c)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in X
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Comment: It would just be `a` at that scope. But, is that what you actually want? Because it won't change with the class attribute, that is, if you mutate `X.a` then the default to `my_method` will still be `'hello'`

Comment: One way to do it. Set the default of `c` to `None` and in the function body assign `c = X.a` if `c` is `None`. [example](https://ideone.com/stTvoM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends what you want, but one way to get what you seem to want is to do it like this.

```
class X:
    a = 'hello'
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, c=None):
        if c is None:
            c = X.a
        print('cls.a = {}'.format(cls.a))
        print('c = {}'.format(c))

X.my_method()
```

Make the default `None` and check for `None` in the function body, assigning to `c` if it is found to be `None`.  If you ever wanted `None` to be a valid argument for the function then it wouldn't work, but that doesn't seem likely.

This idiom is often used in python to avoid the pitfalls mutable default argument, but here it delays the assignment from `X.a` until after `X` has actually been defined.

It also means that if you change `X.a` then `my_method` will pick up the new value. You may or may not want that.